# How to bind variable when calling directive using element.addClass

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, 2-way-object-databinding

I am calling directive adding a class to element and compiling element
eg

```
var el = angular.element(document.querySelector(".ctrl-outer-container"));
el.addClass('directive-name);
$compile(el)(scope);
```

while calling directive this way How can I bind variable that I am passing to directive (2 way binding)

I tried with

```
el.attr('attr-name', attr.value)
```